# Need to execute script file using sudo user - run from teamcity

Tags: java, ant, exec, teamcity, sudo

I need to execute a script in Linux platform "runme.sh" (which can be executed as sudo user) using another ant script "build.xml". Now i have execute this build.xml from teamcity.

I have code for everything but got struck into while invoking "runme.sh" using sudo in build.xml from team city.

In build.xml i have code like

```
    <exec dir="${installdir}" executable="/bin/sh">
        <arg line="-c 'sudo ./runme.sh'"/>
        <redirector inputstring="sudopassword"/>        
    </exec>
```

In team city I get error as "   [exec] sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo".

Can someone please help me resolve this error?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your machine has sudo set up with the `requiretty` option enabled.  You could disable this option, but it creates a security hole; a better solution is to use `su --session-command` instead.  See [this link](http://maymay.net/blog/2010/03/17/how-to-work-around-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo-without-sacrificing-security/) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: The link says Not Found